# Salesforce as a data mesh

Tags: salesforce, data-warehouse, data-mesh

Salesforce and Tableau offers a compelling solution to bring reporting, analytics and data science closer to the source. In my  view this offers many benefits of data mesh thinking (Zhamak etc.).

It’s almost data architecture as a service.

Decentralised domain ownership - easy
Data Products - easy
Self serve data infrastructure platform - yes
Federated computational data governance - yes

Has anyone else used Salesforce & Tableau as a way to start a data mesh journey, and would you recommend this approach to creating a great data culture inside a very immature (data wise) organisation?

Previously, A centralised data warehouse built by an outsourced company and is used by no one and delivers no value.

Answer (score 0):

Using Salesforce and Tableau as a way to start a data mesh journey can be a good approach, especially for organizations that are immature when it comes to data culture. However, it's important to note that data mesh is more than just a technology solution. It requires a shift in mindset and culture towards empowering domain experts to take ownership of their data, and promoting collaboration and communication between teams.

In terms of using Salesforce and Tableau specifically, it's important to ensure that the tools are aligned with the organization's overall data strategy and goals, and that the implementation is done in a way that supports the [principles of data mesh](https://martinfowler.com/articles/data-mesh-principles.html). This may require changes to the organization's data governance and architecture practices, as well as training and support for domain experts who will be using the tools.